# How to handle multi level array as input parameter from custom POST webservice in Magento2

Tags: magento2, module, api, rest-api

We have request to create custom REST webservice for creating gift orders and we are successfully able to create order for single item but facing issues on taking multi items as input.

Can anyone help please?

We have created below files to handle

1. CreateOrderInterface

   ```
   interface CreateOrderInterface
   {

       /**
        * @param string $giftCardCode
        * @return boolean;
        * @throws \Exception
        */
       public function checkGiftCard($giftCardCode);

       /**
        * @param XYZ\GiftCard\Api\JsondataInterface $orderData
        * @param XYZ\GiftCard\Api\AddressdataInterface $customerAddress
        * @param XYZ\GiftCard\Api\BillingdataInterface $billingAddress
        * @param XYZ\GiftCard\Api\ShippingdataInterface $shippingAddress
        * @param XYZ\GiftCard\Api\ItemsdataInterface $items
        * @return string;
        * @throws \Exception
        */
       public function createOrder($orderData, $customerAddress,$billingAddress,$shippingAddress,$items);
   }
   ```
2. createOrder Model

   ```
   class createOrder
   {
       /**
        * @param \XYZ\GiftCard\Api\Kensium\GiftCard\Api\JsondataInterface $jsonOrderData
        * @param \XYZ\GiftCard\Api\Kensium\GiftCard\Api\AddressdataInterface $customerAddress
        * @param \XYZ\GiftCard\Api\Kensium\GiftCard\Api\BillingdataInterface $billingAddress
        * @param \XYZ\GiftCard\Api\Kensium\GiftCard\Api\ShippingdataInterface $shippingAddress
        * @param \XYZ\GiftCard\Api\Kensium\GiftCard\Api\ItemsdataInterface $items
        * @return array|string
        * @throws \Exception
        * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
        * @throws bool
        */
       public function createOrder($jsonOrderData, $customerAddress, $billingAddress, $shippingAddress,$items)
       {
           $invalidType = array();
           $invalidSku = array();
           $invalidAmount = array();
           print_r($jsonOrderData->getItems());die;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To pass an array of items annotation should be specified in the following format:

`@param \XYZ\GiftCard\Api\ItemsdataInterface[] $items`

Square brackets here mean, that you are passing an indexed array containing objects of `\XYZ\GiftCard\Api\ItemsdataInterface` type.

One more note regarding `@return array|string`, all parameters/return values in Magento 2 web API must be concrete types, it is not allowed to specify types like `int|string` for example. It is possible however to use `string|null`, which means that this value is optional. Also `array` should never be used, instead use `string[]`, `\Custom\Type[]` which would let the system know array of which types is declared.

Comment: @Alex how to do same in magneto1.9?