# Passing Array in REST Api Magento2 (Post Method)

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento-2.0.7

I have created many rest Api in magento2 which working perfectly... I have only problem to pass the array in custom rest api...
for example I am passing the data in below format from postman.

> {"vendor_data":{"name":"Mujassam", "mobile":7777}}

It gives me below error:

> **"message": "Class array does not exist",
>     "code": -1,**

Api interface is as below,

```
/**
 * return placed order status
 * @api
 * @param array[] $vendor_data
 * @return array
 */
public function createVendor($vendor_data);
```

**EDIT:** tried this but no luck

[How to handle multi level array as input parameter from custom POST webservice in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109457/how-to-handle-multi-level-array-as-input-parameter-from-custom-post-webservice-i)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Magento 2 do not support mixed like array. You can use KayValue[] or string[] but do not array[]

see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html for more details

Answer (score 17):

I also faced the same issue and got it fixed.Try this,

```
     /**
     * return placed order status
     * @api
     * @param mixed $vendor_data
     * @return array
     */
    public function createVendor($vendor_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Type mixed is available from version 2.2 onwards.
@saravanavelu's answer won't work in versions before that.

See docs: [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html)