# M2.1.x REST API - Invalid type for value array. Expected type: string

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

Having some conflicts with a REST API I created. Trying to pass an array of strings; for example, "skus", but I get this error:

`Invalid type for value: array. Expected type: string.`

**{vendor}/{module}/etc/webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">

    <route url="/V1/to/api/rules/group/guest" method="POST">
        <service class="{Vendor}\{Module}\Api\ProductCheckInterface" method="checkProductsAsGuest" />

        <!--this will change later-->
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**{Vendor}/{Module}/Api/ProductCheckInterface**

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Api;

interface ProductCheckInterface
{
    /**
     * Check a group of products with rules as a guest
     *
     * @param string[] $skus
     * @return \{Vendor}\{Module}\Api\Data\ProductsActionInterface
     */
    public function checkProductsAsGuest($skus);
}
```

**{Vendor}/{Module}/Model/ProductCheck**

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Model;

class ProductCheck implements \{Vendor}\{Module}\Api\ProductCheckInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function checkProductsAsGuest($skus)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

I've went around the web, but nothing helped.

- [Passing Array in REST Api Magento2 (Post Method)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141307/passing-array-in-rest-api-magento2-post-method)
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html
- https://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/

Comment: How's your input string look like?